# Android Application (Network Unavailable) & LogCat won't show anything

Tags: android, connection, logcat

I was testing my blog reader application at my friends house (on my laptop) and it connected to the network and the parsing of all the JSON worked great. As soon as I get home I go to test it and it can't seem to connect to a Network. My laptop is connected to my internet (no issues with browsing internet) and my emulator does not have airplane mode on.

Also apparently my LogCat decided to go on vacation because it is not outputting ANY info at all.

the console has been outputting this

```
[2013-08-29 19:43:24 - BlogReader] Android Launch!
[2013-08-29 19:43:24 - BlogReader] adb is running normally.
[2013-08-29 19:43:24 - BlogReader] Performing com.practice.blogreader.MainListActivity activity launch
[2013-08-29 19:43:25 - BlogReader] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Nexus_4_Emulator'
[2013-08-29 19:43:26 - BlogReader] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-08-29 19:43:26 - BlogReader] Starting activity com.practice.blogreader.MainListActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-08-29 19:43:27 - BlogReader] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.practice.blogreader/.MainListActivity }
[2013-08-29 19:43:27 - BlogReader] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its    current task has been brought to the front
```

Even though the only thing that is displayed on the emulator is the application.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Its seems like your activity was already running. close the application, and again start it. it should work. In the console that you have provided, it can be easily seen that, activity not started. just quit the app hitting back button of emulator and run the app again.

Comment: ah, I was not fully exiting the app apparently... I did a force stop and it works. Feeling like a bit of an idiot but greatly appreciate your suggestion.